# Docker Desktop, Kubernetes and MySql : cannot mount volume on /var/lib/mysql/

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I need the /var/lib/mysql directory to be mounted as a persistent volume so that the contents of the database are not lost each time my PC restarts (I use Docker desktop and Windows).

But when starting the Pod, I have the following error:

```
2023-03-07 21:10:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.32-1.el8 started.
find: '/var/lib/mysql/': Operation not permitted
find: '/var/lib/mysql': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql': Operation not permitted
```

Here is the deployment file:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 500M
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /c/data/db
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - docker-desktop

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-storage
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500M

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
  - port: 3306 
    targetPort: 3306

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-lb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mysql
  name: mysql
spec:
  serviceName: mysql
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql:latest
          name: mysql
          ports:
          - containerPort: 3306
          resources: {}        
          volumeMounts:
          - name: mysql-volume
            mountPath: /var/lib/mysql 
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
                  name: mysql-env
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: MYSQL_ROOT_USERNAME
                  name: mysql-env
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pvc
```

If I use another mountpath for the volume, the pod starts, but of course the database content is lost each time I restart my computer.

I also tried to change the owner of the directory by executing a chown command before mounting the volume:

```
      containers:
        - image: mysql:latest
          name: mysql
          ports:
          - containerPort: 3306
          resources: {}  
          command:
          - chown
          - -R
          - 999:999
          - /var/lib/mysql          
          volumeMounts:
          - name: mysql-volume
            mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
```

But I get the following error when starting the pod :
`chown: cannot read directory '/var/lib/mysql': Operation not permitted`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Grenat welcome to SO. You will want to use the [extensive search feature](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdocker%5D+chown+%22operation+not+permitted%22) of the Stacx Exchange sites because there are very few new problems under the sun. If you have explored all those answered questions and found they don't fix your problem, you'll want to include that information in your question to help people to help you. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 999
    allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

on StatefulSet component